# javascript code not working locally but works in jsfiddle

Tags: javascript, html

i am trying to  focus the next input once the previous input has reached its maxlength value. But it is not working with my code.

```
  <html>
  <head>
    <script>
        var a = document.getElementById("num1"),
            b = document.getElementById("num2"),
            c = document.getElementById("num3");

        a.onkeyup = function() {
            if (this.value.length === parseInt(this.attributes["maxlength"].value)) {
                b.focus();
            }
        }
        b.onkeyup = function() {
           if (this.value.length === parseInt(this.attributes["maxlength"].value)) {
               c.focus();
            }
        }
    </script>
  </head>

<body>
    <input type="text" id="num1" maxlength="3">
    <input type="text" id="num2" maxlength="2">
    <input type="text" id="num3" maxlength="6">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The script should be loaded after the body, or at least your logic should be wrapped within a DOM ready handler. As the script is in the head, it is executed because the body has completely loaded: and in that case, the elements are not available at runtime.

Comment: Please [search](/search?q=%5Bjs%5D+doesn%27t+work+but+works+in+fiddle) before posting. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the edited code with the following edit:

- Semicolon in the end of variables definitions wasn't correct.
- Move the script to the end of the code, not the beginning. It would lead to null pointing of variables because the elements were not there at the time of the definitions.

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>     <!--script moved down-->
> </head>
> <body>
>     <input type="text" id="num1" maxlength="3">
>     <input type="text" id="num2" maxlength="2">
>     <input type="text" id="num3" maxlength="6">
>
>     <script>
>         //semicolon correction here
>         var a = document.getElementById("num1");
>         var b = document.getElementById("num2");
>         var c = document.getElementById("num3");
>
>         a.onkeyup = function() {
>             if (this.value.length === parseInt(this.attributes["maxlength"].value)) {
>                 b.focus();
>             }
>         };
>         b.onkeyup = function() {
>             if (this.value.length === parseInt(this.attributes["maxlength"].value)) {
>                 c.focus();
>             }
>         };
>     </script>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in defining those 3 variables, instead of comma, you should add semi-colon OR you can add comma but remove `var` from `b` and `c`:

```js
var a = document.getElementById("num1");
var b = document.getElementById("num2");
var c = document.getElementById("num3");

/*
var a = document.getElementById("num1"),
b = document.getElementById("num2"),
c = document.getElementById("num3");
*/


a.onkeyup = function() {
  if (this.value.length === parseInt(this.attributes["maxlength"].value)) {
    b.focus();
  }
}
b.onkeyup = function() {
  if (this.value.length === parseInt(this.attributes["maxlength"].value)) {
    c.focus();
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="num1" maxlength="3">
<input type="text" id="num2" maxlength="2">
<input type="text" id="num3" maxlength="6">
```